# PostGIS error with working expression

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, expression

I'm using OSM-Data via PostGIS (osm2pgsql). To draw a highway with and without bridges or tunnels, I use the following expressions:

The highway:

```
"highway" = 'motorway' AND "bridge" IS NOT 'yes' AND "tunnel" IS NOT 'yes'
```

To draw bridges and tunnels for their own I use that expressions:

```
"highway" = 'motorway' AND ("bridge"  =  'yes' OR "bridge"  =  'suspension')

"highway" = 'motorway' AND "tunnel"  =  'yes'
```

So far so good. Was working fine for me for years, but now I kept an eye on my PostGIS log and found that:

```
Result: 7 (ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'yes'"
        LINE 1: ...h') OR ("highway" = 'footway')) AND ("bridge" IS NOT 'yes'))
```

It seems, there is something working wrong, but what? Bridges, tunnels and the highways are drawn as they should - I can not see any error, but PostGIS is telling me something else.
Is there a better way to draw OSM-Roads with bridges and tunnels?

ADD: the whole line:

```
2016-11-08T22:12:43 1   1 cursor states lost.
        SQL: DECLARE qgis_9 BINARY CURSOR FOR SELECT st_asbinary("way",'NDR'),"gid","route"::text,"service"::text,"name"::text,"aeroway"::text,"tunnel"::text,"highway"::text,"bridge"::text,"railway"::text,"ref"::text FROM "public"."planet_osm_line" WHERE ("way" && st_makeenvelope(426908.41326787287835032,5749630.84951520431786776,436049.76744384958874434,5752852.1516018183901906,32632)) AND (((((((("highway" = 'path') OR ("highway" = 'footway')) AND ("bridge" IS NOT 'yes')) AND ("tunnel" IS NOT 'yes')) AND ("bridge" IS NOT 'suspension')) OR ((("highway" = 'path') OR ("highway" = 'footway')) AND ("tunnel" = 'yes'))) OR ((("highway" = 'path') OR ("highway" = 'footway')) AND (("bridge" = 'yes') OR ("bridge" = 'suspension')))))
        Result: 7 (ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'yes'"
        LINE 1: ... OR ("highway" = 'footway')) AND ("bridge" IS NOT 'yes')) AN...
                                                                     ^
        )
```

Comment: For not equal comparison, shouldn't you use `!=`? instead of `IS NOT`

Comment: Please add also the whole line that leads to error.

Comment: Quite a long query. I would start debugging by rewriting the WHERE to have first just AND "highway"='path' and adding more elements one by one and testing the query with pgAdmin after each addition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are using the `IS NOT` syntax instead of the `IS DISTINCT FROM` syntax.

If what you want is all records where bridge is equal to 'no' or is NULL and tunnel is equal to 'no' or is NULL, then the correct syntax would be :

```
"bridge" IS DISTINCT FROM 'yes' AND "tunnel" IS DISTINCT FROM 'yes'
```

`IS NOT` is meant to be used with booleans, i.e. `expression IS TRUE` or `expression IS NOT TRUE`.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html

As for why this would work, I have no idea.